# Fluctuating response times for Azure website

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a .Net web app hosted on Azure and am on the S1 Production pricing tier (1x core, 1.75 GB memory, A-Series compute). What's weird is I am going through extended periods of poor performance. Usually my average response time is around the 1.4 s mark. Not good by any stretch but it's something I can work with. However I'm experiencing extended periods where the response time shoots up to around the 5 s or greater mark. These periods last for days, up to a week, before coming back to normal levels. My knowledge of Azure is pretty limited but I can't seem to find anything that would explain this.

[average response time over the last 30 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W9wP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might first want to identify if this is an issue with your web app itself or is this the trend of app usage(i.e. it receives max hits during specific weeks of a month).

There are several areas you might want to look for  further diagnosis. A few are -

1. Look for the number of requests during the time  the website is slow. This is a web part on the website overview page.

[image]

2. Check the diagnose and  solve problems. It is self-service diagnostic and troubleshooting experiencing to help you resolve issues with your web app. 
   [image]
3. If you have a considerable user base(number of users) and its a production environment sometimes a 1 Core + 1.75 GB RAM might not be sufficient to bear the load. If you determine that this is due to a usage trend from your users then you can plan for scaling out/up your application to meet the demands of high usage.

[image]